# Cygwin error: system not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, bash, cygwin

I am currently experimenting with Cygwin, just started trying it today when I encountered this problem.

This is my MSVS 2010 C++ code for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Compiling it and running it on Visual Studio itself runs just fine. However on the Cygwin bash, after inserting the following command:

```
 $ g++ -Wall -g -o Test.exe main.cpp
```

When I run the `Test.exe`, the console closes almost immediately and under the Hello World line, it says something like:

```
sh:pause: command not found.
```

It's bit hard to see since it closes so fast. Anybody knows why?

Not sure if this is related, but when the

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

is excluded, the error on the cygwin bash will be:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g -o Test.exe main.cpp
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:10:18: error: `system' was not declared in this scope
system("pause");
                  ^
```

Is this the right way to solve the error? Documentation and tutorials on Cygwin is difficult to find, so I am not entirely sure if `#include <cstdlib>` is correct too.

Comment: Why would excluding the `#include <cstdlib>`, which as you've already seen causes a syntax error, be "the right way to solve the error"? You need either `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <stdlib.h>` because that's where the `system` function is declared.

Comment: So your question in fact is two unrelated questions. Why?

Comment: @keith, Yup. I know that. It's just that the Linux environment is new to me, first few hours learning it now by myself. In windows environment, whenever I use system, I never include the library stated or at least rarely, and it runs just fine. But when i used that, the program doesn't seem to work the way I want after cygwin, hence I was confused whether the declaration of the library was the cause of the program not running like in Windows environment.

Comment: Cygwin is not Linux; see http://cygwin.com. MSVS tends to provide an automatic `#include "stdafx.h"`, which indirectly includes some standard headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* need it to work in both environments call `system("cmd /C pause")` instead of `system("pause")`. This will force the Windows shell to start and then invoke it's pause command.

Answer (score 1):

`system` runs the command given to it, which means it's completely platform-dependent. `pause` is a Windows command. Cygwin provides a Linux-like environment, in which `pause` is not a command. However, if you're running it from the Cygwin command line, you should have no reason to pause or sleep at the end of `main` (and in fact, you shouldn't really do it in Windows either - if you need to stop at the end, set a breakpoint).

Comment: the Test.exe generated by cygwin closes immediately. I have another way of stopping it, which is, cout<<"\nPress any key and hit enter to end..."; followed by cin>>x; which works. Setting a breakpoint in the Visual Studio itself work and runs perfectly when running in Visual Studio. But the Test.exe generated by cygwin will still close immediately. :( I was wondering why the system method doesn't work. Thanks for the answer(:

Comment: @rockinfresh As it should do. A program should always close when it's done. Your best bet is to run your program from the cygwin command line, then it will just print output to the terminal which you can continue to read even after it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that there's nothing like windows `pause` command is found by the cygwin shell that is executed from the `system()` call. To have it being found you'll need to add the windows system directory to cygwin's `PATH` variable.

Your second error is a compilation error for the program itself, since `#include <cstdlib` is missing (which contains a declaration for `std::system()`).